# The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event - Wix fetch error

Tags: google-api, fetch, velo

I'm using Google Analytics API to query user account and view
to do so, I'm using multiple WIX fetch functions (each fetch function depends on the previous one), here is one of them:

```
export function GetGAView (access_token, account_id,webPropertyId){

const url1 = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/"
const url2 = account_id
const url3 =  "/webproperties/"
const url4 =  webPropertyId
const url5 =  "/profiles?oauth_token="
const url6 = access_token


const url =url1.concat(url2,url3,url4,url5,url6).toString()
  console.log(url, 'view url')
return fetch(url, {"method": "get"})
  .then( (httpResponse) => {
    if (httpResponse.ok) {
      return httpResponse.json();
    } else {
      return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
    }
  } )
  .then(json => {//console.log(json)
  return json
    }
      )

  .catch(err => console.log(err));



}
```

4 of 11 working well (same function distinguished by account id and properties id)and 7 functions return the following error shown on the console :

**The error**

```
/ga/oauth2callback?code=4%2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&scope=email+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics&authuser=0&prompt=none:1 **The resource https://static.parastorage.com/services/editor-elements/dist/componentSdks.a8951fd0.bundle.min.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.**
```

What does this error mean? How to solve this issue?
The only place I found the same error is here
https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/community-discussion/parastorage-link-preload-failure